# Android - Bitmap issue with device memory

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I am using a bitmap to draw more than one drawing on the same canvas. Say, I am drawing lines, circles with different radii to the same canvas. My requirement is to add 2000 such canvas to my MapView. The image looks pixelated if I use 256x256 as bitmap resolution.

So I am using 1024x1024 as bitmap resolution for better quality. Now when I run this on Android devices with low memory, my app freezes and crashes.

Problem statement :

1. Bitmap size - 1024*1024 = works fine in devices having more memory like one plus devices but freezes on the low storage[less than 4 GB]
2. Bitmap size - 256 * 256 = works fine in both Android devices.

Here is the code Snippet Currently using to draw on canvas by using a bitmap.

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1024, 1024, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
```

// drawing circle

```
 canvas.drawCircle(width/2, height/2, 2, paint);
```

// drawing line

```
canvas.drawLine(cx, cy, x2, y2, paint);
```

// Same canvas with different radius

```
canvas.drawArc(endgunRect, startAngle - 90, endSweep, false, paint);
```

Solution expected :
I need to load around 2000 devices on the map view of the app in all types of Android devices irrespective of devices storage capacity?

Could anyone advise is there any other approach we have than Bitmap on the canvas?

Comment: `When I try to load 700+ devices on the map view,` ??? Loading devices? On the map view? You did not talk about a map view yet? Completely unclear what you try to do.

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap are stored in `bitmap heap` which is in `Dalvik heap` and often causes memory issue when used in larger number.
I also faced the similar issue and there are few points you can use in order to ensure that devices never goes out of memory.

1. Try to reduce the size of bitmap , or make it dynamic according to device size.
2. Reuse of bitmap, all bitmap won't be unique so it better to store comman bitmaps in hashmap and reuse them.
3. Don't load all bitmap at once, only load the overlaps visible to the user on the screen. Override `scroll listener` on the maps and load more as user scrolls.
4. **Most Important** - Release bitmaps as soon as not in use using `bitmap.release`